# Getting $scope variable undefined in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

When i initialize the **$scope.s** with some value it's working properly.
But when it's not initialize  with any value as shown below, it generates error in console saying 
**$scope.s undefined** on click event bind with button

```
 var mainApp = angular.module('mainApp', ['ngRoute']);
mainApp.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {


$scope.title = 'Home page';
$scope.s = '';
$scope.m = '';
$scope.subscribe = function () {


    console.log($scope.s); // undefined


}
}]);

<div data-ng-app="mainApp" data-ng-controller="homeCtrl">
<div>
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
</div>
<div>
    <h3>Want to become a seller and earn more..?</h3>
    <p>Add your email and we will get in touch.</p>
    <div>
        <input type="email" data-ng-model="s" id="txtEmail" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>                
            <button data-ng-click="subscribe();">Send</button>
        </div>            
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    {{m}}
</div>
```

Comment: @georgeawg , so what's proper solution. Do we have to initialize it with some value. As here i had bind it with textbox, so initializing it with some value will give default text  in textbox. Any help??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$scope.s`variable is undefined because you are using input of type `email` and having the value a non-valid email.

This 'feature' doesn't seem to be well documented, but the example at angular's documentation for `input[email]` clearly shows the same behavior: [input[email] @ docs.angularjs.org](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bemail%5D); try an valid and an invalid email address in their example and you're see the same behavior as you are witnessing.

So your options are: switch to input of type `text` or plan on your model being undefined unless the email is valid.

Here is issue within angularjs's github that goes back to 2012 with the same behavior:

> [Binding doesn't work with input type="email"](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1426)